# how to retrieve attributes using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get ALL attributes from "server" below:

This is the XML file(partial):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<server xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="udsServerInfo.xsd" id="57672acc-4ba7-4876-811a-1629eca853ed" productPath="C:\Tools\UDS\udsServerInfo\" osActivated="true">
  <networkAdapters>
    <networkAdapter id="6ad45274-6077-4a46-9b5c-d4e7be712310"...
```

Here is the code which returns NULL for "server":

```
    var server = (from node in doc.Attributes("server")
                       select node);
```

I am able to get all networkAdapters by calling doc.Descendants("networkAdapter") but haven't figured out how to obtain the attributes .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming `doc` is an `XDocument`):

```
var attributes = doc.Descendants("server").Attributes();
```

or

```
var id = doc.Descendants("server").Attributes("id");
```

or

```
var productPath = doc.Descendants("server").Attributes("productPath");
```

etc

Comment: I am using TextReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
var doc = XElement.Load(sr); Once I changed to XDocument everything worked. -- Thank you!!!